POSTing a file to sharepoint sub-site returns a 403, while it works on the root
My python script below to upload a file (without a specific user account) to a sharepoint is working, however only when I upload to the root. When I try to use the url of a sub-site I receive a 403 error:
{'error': {'code': '-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException', 'message':
{'lang': 'en-US', 'value': 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'}}}

My code:
import requests

client_id = '***'
client_secret = '***'
tenant_id = '***'
host = "mycompany.sharepoint.com"

data = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": f"{client_id}@{tenant_id}",
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "resource": f"00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/{host}@{tenant_id}"
}
response = requests.post(
    f"https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{tenant_id}/tokens/OAuth/2", data=data)

access_token = response.json()['access_token']
file_path = '/home/myuser/foo.txt'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
}

with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    url = f"https://{host}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')/Files/add(url='foo.txt', overwrite=true)"
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files={"file": file})
    print(response.json())
    print(response.status_code)
    assert response.status_code == 200

With that I can see my file in mycompany.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/ or what Microsoft also calls "Communication Site". But I need to place the file in a sub-site.
I tried among others:
    url = f"https://{host}/sites/mysubsite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')/Files/add(url='foo.txt', overwrite=true)"

As a permission I gave my app the following:
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>

Are my permissions wrong or my API call?

Access denied, Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation, or 403 are the expected results because you are using a client secret. Due to security reinforcement, only certificate will work.

FAQ: Can I use other means besides certificates for realizing app-only access for my Azure AD app?
No, all other options are blocked by SharePoint Online and will result
in an Access Denied message.

Source: Granting access via Azure AD App-Only
Try to generate a certificate for your application with application permissions Sites.FullControl.All and use it to connect to SharePoint.

